# Regular Expression PHP regex issue in a specific scenario

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

Having a little problem. I am trying to use preg_match_all but some how the regular expression doesn't work for one of the case.

```
<tr>
    <td class="FieldTitle" valign="top">EAN code:</td>
    <td class="Field" valign="top">3838942897078</td>

</tr>
```

On the above code is in variable $html

```
$table_html = $html;
preg_match_all("'EAN code:</td>\s*<td class=\"Field\" valign=\"top\">(.*?)</td>'si",$table_html,$extract);
$ean = $extract[1][0];
return $ean;
```

This returns 3838942897078. This is correct but the same code for a different scenario gives out an empty array of var_dump of $extract. Which does mean that I did not find any match.

```
<div class="Field"><span class="Title">Dimensions of the product (W&#215;H&#215;D): </span>60 &#215; 152,4 &#215; 64 cm</div>
```

The above is in $html

And the below code:

```
$table_html = $html;
preg_match_all("'Dimensions of the product (W&#215;H&#215;D):</span>(.*?)</div>'si",$table_html,$extract);
var_dump($extract);
```

This shows that in the dump that array is empty. Can some one throw some light on the issue. I have already tried both preg_match and preg_match_all with no luck. Help is much appreciated. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Stop using regex to parse HTML. Use a [DOM parser](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Comment: Why do you expect them to match? Do you know what your regex matches? Do you also know you would be better off with a proper HTML parser?

Comment: Try to add `m` modifier to regexp (`...'si` ⇒ `...'sim`) for multiline.

Comment: hi guys... thanks for the comment. Well I am a N00b to parsing. And after almost 5 hrs of trial and error yesterday on DOM . I did gave up with the lack of lucid documentation to go thru. And suggestion for a good basic tutorial ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
$table_html = $html;
preg_match_all("'Dimensions of the product \(W&#215;H&#215;D\): </span>(.*?)</div>'si",$table_html,$extract);
var_dump($extract);
```

You needed to escape the brackets around `W&#215;H&#215;D` using a backslash `\`.

As Sergey notes, you also have a `</td>` in your pattern, which should be replaced with a single space to match against your HTML string.

Comment: Thanks for Reply @Zougen . Well </td> was just me trying around on a different part of markup. But as you specified the real issue was the brackets around which had to be escaped. Working perfectly fine. Many thanks. Really appreciated. Thanks.